# CPU performance in task manager is 100%

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, performance, motherboard, gpu

Here is my problem:
I was playing some games in my desktop, so i got bored from these games so i decided to get new motherboard, i got my new motherboard and all installed all my specs including a new GPU (Geforce GTX 540 ti) so i decided to play same game, the FPS Drop-ed so much, so i took a look at the CPU performance at the task manager and i found it was about 100%, i got shocked, so i took a look at PCP health status in the motherboard bios, i found that everything is fine, the cpu temp is 30-35c , everything runs fine, so i thought it was GPU problem, i changed to my old GPU, same thing happen-ed, so i took my motherboard to a guys that know better then me, they told me there is nothing wrong with it.
what would the problem possible be?

Comment: 30C at 100% load? That seems unrealistic. Did you check the frequency your CPU runs at? e.g. with CPUid HWMonitor.

Comment: well yes, seem unrealistic but , true i can get u pic or somthing

Answer (score -2):

okay guys, i found that my drivers weren't updated so.... yea.

Comment: Its worth mentioning what driver?

Comment: i don't which one exactly, i used Driver Pack solution to update drivers for me